# How to enable Record Macro function in Excel 2010?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, macros

After adding the *Developers* tab in Excel 2010, the *Record Macro* function became disabled.

How can I enable it again?

Answer (score 3):

Save as a Macro Enabled workbook.

> 1) Click the Office button and then click Save As.
>       The Save As dialog box appears.
>
> 2) Enter a name and select a location for your workbook.
>
> 3) Click the Save as Type drop-down arrow.
>       A list of file types appears.
>
> 4) Select Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm).
>       Excel adds the .xlsm extension to the filename.
>
> 5) Click Save.

OR

Change the settings of ***Digital Certificate for VBA Projects*** and ***Visiual Basic for Applications*** to ***Run from My Computer***. Follow this on how to [Install or remove individual Office programs and components](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/install-or-remove-individual-office-programs-and-components-HA010354261.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Even i did first step i didnt understood what the "Change the settings of Digital Certificate for VBA Projects and Visiual Basic for Applications to Run from My Computer."

Comment: Follow the link to change the settings.

Comment: For Office 365, In Windows 10, you can repair Office installation on `Settings`->  `Apps and features`-> `Microsoft Office 365 - en-us` -> `Modify`. When asked pick online repair option.

Answer (score 0):

First click the File Menu(Office Backstage) and select Options from the left sidebar. In options, select Trust Center from the left sidebar and click Trust Center Settings button on the main window.

Now in Trust Center Settings dialog window, select Macro Settings from the left sidebar, choose Enable All Macros option and hit OK.

Comment: I enabelled already that, then also no success. after that only i raised that question can you tell me any other alternative.